# Topology spouts lag error

Tags: apache-storm, hortonworks-data-platform

I am getting some strange error while after storm topology created. In "Topology spouts lag error" part of Storm-UI. It says:

```
Unable to get offset lags for kafka. Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.storm.kafka.monitor.KafkaOffsetLagUtil.getOffsetLags(KafkaOffsetLagUtil.java:269) at org.apache.storm.kafka.monitor.KafkaOffsetLagUtil.main(KafkaOffsetLagUtil.java:127)
```

There is a topic inside kafka and check this topic with /bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh

Any idea? Thank you

[image]

Comment: I am having similar problem with HDP 2.5. Please let me know if you are able to figure out the problem.

Comment: try to increase parallelism hint and worker number.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?